# How to use Weka to merge 2 attributes into 1 attribute with a value between 0.1 and 1?

Tags: class, weka, target, normalize

Excuse me, if weka merges two attributes and adds a new attribute, will the attribute value be between 0.1 and 1?

[image]

Tried using weka Normalize but Normalizes all properties
I only want to take 2 attributes and normalize them
Next I want to combine 2 attributes and the value is between 0.1-1

Comment: What filter did you use for merging the two numeric attributes? I only know of filters that merge two or more labels of a nominal attribute into a new, combined label.